# Postgres nested LEFT OUTER JOIN returns me more than one null in array_agg()

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, nosql-aggregation

I have quite 2 tables:

```
SELECT * FROM clubs_place_rubrics;
  id   | place_id | placerubric_id 
-------+----------+----------------
 20777 |     3626 |              7
(1 row)

SELECT * FROM clubs_placerubric LIMIT 5;
 id |         rubric         
----+------------------------
  1 | Тренажёрные залы
  2 | Фитнес-клубы
  3 | Косметические услуги
  4 | Услуги массажиста
  5 | Ледовые дворцы / Катки
```

So there is some clubs, that have, or have not rubrics at all. From the above example, only one club (id=3626) have rubric #7.

So why this code returns me list of nulls, more than one null ?

```
        SELECT
            place.id, place.title, 
            array_agg(phone.code) phone_code, 
            array_agg(phone.phone) phone_number, 
            array_agg(phone.fax) fax,
            array_agg(email.email) email, 
            array_agg(site.site) site,
            array_agg(rubric.rubric) rubrics
        FROM clubs_place place 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placephone phone 
            ON place.id = phone.place_id 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placeemail email
            ON place.id = email.place_id 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placesite site
            ON place.id = site.place_id 
                LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_place_rubrics rubrics
                ON place.id = rubrics.place_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placerubric rubric
                ON rubric.id = rubrics.placerubric_id

        WHERE project='Москва'
        GROUP BY place.id
        LIMIT 6;


-[ RECORD 4 ]+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id           | 3629
title        | Переделкино, банно-оздоровительный комплекс
phone_code   | {499,495}
phone_number | {7379358,7311313}
fax          | {t,t}
email        | {gup@gup-bok.ru,gup@gup-bok.ru}
site         | {www.gup-bok.ru,www.gup-bok.ru}
rubrics      | {NULL,NULL}
-[ RECORD 5 ]+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id           | 3630
title        | Досуг и здоровье, физкультурно-оздоровительный комплекс
phone_code   | {499}
phone_number | {1281877}
fax          | {f}
email        | {""}
site         | {www.apollon.ru}
rubrics      | {NULL}
-[ RECORD 6 ]+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
id           | 3631
title        | Центр Корона, спортивно-развлекательный центр
phone_code   | {495,495,495}
phone_number | {7532650,7540511,7941880}
fax          | {f,f,f}
email        | {centr-corona@yandex.ru,centr-corona@yandex.ru,centr-corona@yandex.ru}
site         | {"","",""}
rubrics      | {NULL,NULL,NULL}
```

It seems that count of rubrics same as count of phones. But there is no logic. I guess, I've made a mistake in SQL syntax.

Definitely there should be not more than one null at the list of result of rubrics. Same for site, email and all other rows, that haven't any value.

How to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense , if you have more then 2 id's in club_places tha its only connect those with the placeid 3626 in your example ,so the rest will be nulls

Comment: Use `array_agg(distinct rubric.rubric)` to remove repeated values.

Comment: Thanks @Abelisto, can you please rapidly explain why this happens? I completely new in SQL. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kAldown If you are completely new in SQL then it is impossible to explain **rapidly** :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If there are more than one entry on any of these tables:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placephone phone 
ON place.id = phone.place_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placeemail email
ON place.id = email.place_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_placesite site
ON place.id = site.place_id
```

then you'll have multiple place records, and your

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN clubs_place_rubrics rubrics
ON place.id = rubrics.place_id
```

join will when join multiple times.  Once you aggregate, those multiple row's NULLs will show up in the aggregate.

Could you confirm that place_id is not duplicated in any of these: clubs_placephone, clubs_placeemail, and clubs_placesite?

If there are duplicates, then you'll likely want to use a subquery to make those joins one to one to avoid duplicates.